# Using array of observable functions with each items output being the next items input

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an array of functions that return observables that I would like to execute in sequence using each functions observable output as the next functions input until each function in the array has been called.

How can I best return this as one observable?

The function type that I have an array of:

```ts
export type FilterFn = (items: Item[]) => Observable< Item[] >;
```

Comment: like loop though the function array and assign the observable to the observable after  calling the function ?

Comment: let observalbe$ =firstObservable  functionsArray.forEach(filterFunction=>{observable$=observable$[filterFunction]();})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce` to chain each fn with a `switchMap` operator

Like this:

```ts
fns.reduce(
  (acc, fn) => acc.pipe( switchMap(fn) ) // switchMap to next fn result
  , of(undefined)                        // initial value to pass to the first fn
)
  .subscribe(result=>{
    console.log(result);
  })
```

Heres a [playground example for this](https://thinkrx.io/gist/10c409101c4c1ff21e4b60c17bd2de06).

Comment: @user10103655, updated to use `switchMap` instead of previous `map`. Note that `of` is a `import {of} from 'rxjs'`

Comment: This looks promising but "acc" is of type "FilterFn" and as such I cant do "acc.pipe" since it is not an observable, it is a FilterFn that returns an observable. Sorry for my title, it is not observable functions but functions that returns observables.

Comment: @user10103655, `acc` will be of type `Observable<...>` as we init reduce `acc` with `of(undefined)`. I've added a playground with an example to my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right, my bad. But what if I need to pass a second parameter like this:export type FilterFn = (items: Item[], somethingElse: string) => Observable< Item[] >;

Comment: @user10103655, I've kinda shortened the print, but you can still do `switchMap(items => fn(items, 'other', 'values'))`